# How to send one msg to next module after receiving all messages from previous module in OMNET++

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

Need your help.

I have three modules  Module A, Module B and Module C.

Module A sends 20 messages to Module B.  I want to send one packet to Module C after receiving all 20 messages from Module A. how I can deal with this situation on handleMessage ?

At the moment it is running like a loop. on every arrival its sending a msg out. what i need is to collect all the messages from previous module, collect data from them, prepare a single message and send one msg to next module.

=================================================

## Thanks [000102](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11550345/000102),

your first solution working perfectly fine. I am only struggling with second solution. so please help me out on this. Please check the below code and let me know where I am wrong.

```
class ModuleB: public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
private:
    bool sentMessage = false;
    simtime_t lastMessageReceivedAt;
    simtime_t timer;
};

void ModuleB::initialize()
{

}

void ModuleB::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
       if(simTime() - lastMessageReceivedAt >= timer && sentMessage == false)
            {
                 EV << counter << " messages to receive before sending.\n";
                // Data collection
            }
            else
            {
                lastMessageReceivedAt = simTime();
                EV << " Send message to Module C.\n";
                cMessage *newMsg = new cMessage("Message")
                send(newMsg, "out");
                sentMessage = true;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
class ModuleB : public cSimpleModule {
  private:
    int counter;

  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

void ModuleB::initialize() {
    counter = 20;
}

void ModuleB::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    counter--;
    if (counter > 0) {
        EV << counter << " messages to receive before sending.\n";
        // Data collection
    }
    else {
        EV << " Send message to Module C.\n";
        cMessage *newMsg = new cMessage("Message");
        send(newMsg, "out");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and how I can deal with the issue where number of incoming messages is unknown?

Comment: In that case, you just need to replace the if condition by something similar to `if (simTime() - lastMessageReceivedAt >= timer && sentMessage == false)`. Add `lastMessageReceivedAt = simTime();` in the else condition and `sentMessage = true;` once your module B has send the packet to Module C.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is perfectly fine where number of packets are know. I am struggling with second solution. I updated question, please check and let me know where I am wrong. I think something related to timer.

Comment: You need to setup your **timer** in `initialize()` as you did before for the counter. Also add `lastMessageReceivedAt = simTime();` **after** the else condition and not inside (my bad here). You actually want to know the last time your module received a message and compare this value with your timer cf. `simTime() - lastMessageReceivedAt >= timer`. When _ModuleB_ hasn't received a message for a while, it sends a message to _ModuleC_

Comment: Its working but other way round. it send the message before processing other messages. because lastMessageReceivedAt is 0 initially so the if statement is true at first stage and after setting lastMessageReceivedAt = simTime() it never goes back to that if statement.

Comment: Just make sure you have received one message before entering in the if/else statement condition.